# Как правильно создать форму?

Tags: java, javafx

Наверное мой вопрос совсем глупый, но я совсем новичок в гуишном деле, а курсач сам себя не сделает, тем более на пятерку. В общем, идея такая: есть форма для заказа товара, сначала идет список категорий товаров (данные берутся из БД), после выбора категории на панели материализуется такой же список товаров из этой категории, и в конце так же материализуется ввод количества, лейбл с ценой и кнопка купить. В чем собственно вопрос. Какой элемент использовать для списков (они должны вмещать  бесконечное колличество элементов и, желательно не резать названия товаров) и как заставить элементы появляться после определенных действий? Сцены рисую в Scene Build'ере.

Answer (score 0):

Используй

```
javafx.scene.control.ListView
```

обернутый в скролл панель.
Когда добавляешь что-то в список, убедись что ты это делаешь в потоке JavaFX Application Thread - все модификации UI должны осуществляться именно в этом потоке.

C помощью этой конструкции запускают код в потоке JavaFX Application Thread:

```
Platform.runLater(runnable)
```